# spread job equally on Jenkins slaves

Tags: jenkins

I added 3 new slaves to my jenkins master, so at the total my master has 5 powerful slaves. All of them from the same instance type (RAM/CPU, Disks and same network).
My Master jenkins is 2.78.
I am not using "Restrict where this project can be run" plugin. However, Jenkins executes builds mostly on slave1 and slave2. It rarely executes jobs on slaves[3-5].

Is there a configuration option within Jenkins, that prioritises the slaves?

Comment: I found the issue:
Jenkins Slave Node was set to use:  “USAGE = Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node”